# Can Not Open VM Fusion

Tags: windows, vmware-fusion

When trying to open VMFusion I am told "File not Found" with the following extended message "/Users/toddpatti/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Windows XP Home Edition.vmwarevm" does not exist.

IMac 2.4
VM Fusion
Windows XP

Please help!

Comment: When you visit that directory in finder or terminal, does that file exist?

Answer (score 1):

You're not really helping yourself here, firstly this isn't server-related and best asked on our sister site superuser.com. Secondly you don't mention which version of Fusion you're using, whether this is a new installation or an existing one that's suddenly gone wrong - but it looks like you've somehow lost a file, have you tried restoring the lost VM from last backup/time-machine?